# E4 EPartService findPart() throwing java.lang.Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

New to Eclipse RCP (e4), am trying to get a handler to update a UI widget within a Part.

I have tried injecting the `EPartService` to first access the Part by ID, like so:

```
public class Example {

    public static final String PART_ID = “au.org.example.app.part”;

    @Inject
    private EPartService partService;

    public void eventOccured()
    {
        MPart part = partService.findPart(PART_ID); // exception thrown here    
    }

}
```

But this is throwing a NPE.

`findPart()` should at least safely return `null` if the ID were incorrect? So what am I missing?

Am also open to suggestions of relevant tutorials (have worked through some of [Lars Vogella's](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Services/article.html#selectedservices_partservice2) great tutorials, but to no avail for this problem).

Any further info required please let me know.

**EDIT :** Looks like `EPartService` is not being injected? Have I not added it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injection is only done automatically on objects which are known to the Application Model - things like parts and handlers.

For objects which you create you can do injection using the `ContextInjectionFactory`. You can create an object with:

```
@Inject
IEclipseContext context;

...

MyClass myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```

or you can do injection on an existing class instance with:

```
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myClass, context);
```

in this case injection is not done on the class constructor.

There are other variants of `make` and `inject` which have a second context which allows additional values to be added to the context being injected.

Comment: Didn't directly solve my problem (due to another issue in my project), but this does answer the underlying question of using injection outside of the application model. Thanks Greg.