# How to Inject EPartService

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am developing e4 application. I want to inject EPartService outside the Part and Handler
when i am injecting EPartService then i will get null pointer error

```
  public class DisplayRuntimePart {
          @Inject  EPartService partService;
          private void displayPart(){
          MPart part=partService.findPart("com.rcpe4.myproject.part.datapart");                   
          mpart.setVisible(true);
          partService.showPart(mpart, PartState.CREATE);   
    }
  }
```

I am also read this question but till not solve my problem [E4 EPartService findPart() throwing java.lang.Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503116/e4-epartservice-findpart-throwing-java-lang-null-pointer-exception)

**Edit**
I am inject EPartService in Part class. Class URI in Application.e4xml is bundleclass://com.abc.test/com.abc.test.part.MyPart in this class I am write code as follows.

```
      Class Mypart{ 
          @Inject EPartService prtservice;                  
          @Inject
          public MyPart() {
          } 
          @PostConstruct
          public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
             parent.setLayout(new  FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));     
             htmlBrowser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);

         }  
         @PreDestroy
        public void preDestroy() {

        }   
        @Focus
        public void onFocus() {

        }   
        @Persist
        public void save() {

        } 
         public dispalyPart(){  
                MPart mpart=partService.findPart("com.abc.test.part.datapart"); **Here Getting Null Pointer Exception**
                mpart.setVisible(true);
                partService.showPart(mpart, PartState.CREATE);  
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse only does direct injection on objects that it 'knows' about - basically objects mentioned in the application model (e4xmi) files or created using something like `EPartService.showPart`.

If you want to do direct injection on objects that you create then you need to create them using `ContextInjectionFactory`. For example:

```java
@Inject IEclipseContext context;

...

MyClass myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```

you can also do injection on a class created in the normal way with:

```java
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myClass, context);
```

(this will not do injection on the constructor).

Note: Since this code is using direct injection you must run it from a class that the Eclipse application model does know about such as a command handler or an MPart.

Comment: When i am @Inject IEclipseContext context; context object give null pointer exception

Comment: The code sample    DisplayRuntimePart myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(DisplayRuntimePart.class, context);
MPart mpart=partService.findPart("com.rcpe4.myproject.part.datapart");
mpart.setVisible(true);
partService.showPart(mpart, PartState.CREATE);

Comment: You must run this code in a class which is created by Eclipse from the application model so that the injection will work. So a MPart or a Handler or something like that.

Comment: Hi greg-449 I am tried implementing code in Part class as per you say  please see the edited code. but still it give null pointer exception

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? What is null?

Comment: partService reference gives null value in dispalyPart() method when I call this method

Comment: Are you doing a `new Mypart()`?

Comment: greg-449 No, i am not use new MyPart(); i will call displayPart method from other mehod of MyPart

Comment: You could check in the @PostConstruct that the part service has been injected. Then check that you are using the same instance of the class when displayPart is called.